# can i send a tiny database from app inventor via whatsapp

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to send a voice note from app inventor via whatsapp can I do that ,the activity starter isn't helping me at all. I tried creating a file text but still cant get through.It says unsupported file format.

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're asking. But... it seems like it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I am currently learning how to use MIT app inventor, I am asking if I can share files like sound and images from the app via whatsapp

Comment: Right - ok, well... that's a great question for the folks that make whatsapp. Or maybe SuperUser. But not StackOverflow. It has really nothing at all to do with programming. And StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can share via WhatsApp. You need to add element "sharing" for that. 
Here's the example of sharing the image file to the whats app through the app created with app inventor.

But first you need to understand that there are two paths for any files while creating apps with app inventor.

1. Path where files are stored while development (live previews)
2. Path where files are stored after producing the app

path while development is:
**file:///mnt/sdcard/AppInventor/*assets/myFile***

path after production is:
**file:///android_asset/*myFile***

So while using "SHARE" component of app inventor you have to specify both paths to avoid any errors in future.

So here is the app:

**Front End Arrangements:**

[image: app that shares the shown picture]

**Block Arrangements:**
[image: Block Arrangements]

Pay attention to the *if then else* block.
It says if the image is not in the development path then the app is installed in the phone(produced). It saves our time to change path very often(and saves us from error if we forget to change paths)

Snapshot from the app:
[image]

After pressing share button:
[image]

After sharing through whats app:
[image]

Comment: no problem, please mark the answer if it solves your problem so people with similar queries can be helped.